# ByteArray Type Coercion failure when reading from Javascript ExternalInterface call

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am reading in a ByteArray object from an `ExternalInterface` call which is obtaining the `ByteArray` from another `SWF`. The reason for the `Javascript` conduit is because the `ByteArray` data exceeds the `40k` limit of the `LocalConnection class`.

I'm getting the following error:

***TypeError***: `Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@d6f48e1 to flash.utils.ByteArray.`

with this line of code:

```
swfBytes = ExternalInterface.call("getBytes", cacheIdx);
```

swfBytes is an initialized ByteArray object. I'm confident my call to getBytes() is returning a ByteArray object because if I run the following line of code, I get the number of bytes being passed.

```
ExternalInterface.call("getBytes", cacheIdx).bytesAvailable;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it's because of the limit? If not - test it. If yes, I think you should already know the answer - you don't have much options, but to split the object into smaller junks :) There are few options to check the size even without writing it to BA. Is it simple enough so you can split it or? Great question though! :)

Comment: To keep it within the 40k limit you could read over the bytes in 40k lengths to your receiving SWF and keep appending (concatenate) to an existing bytearray there, basically building it up in 40k blocks until ready to use. For that you need a `While` loop and also a `position_counter++` to keep incrementing the read position in the source SWF bytes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Splitting the data into 40k chunks worked well. Now I have another issue, which is the inability to properly close and reuse the connection. Another answered question suggested using a unique connection string for each connection.