# Localconnection succeeds on first connection, fails on subsequent attempts

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I've built a preloader/cache mechanism using two SWFs in two frames of a frameset. The one SWF caches multiple SWFs in a static frame as and array of ByteArray objects. The other SWF is loaded with each new HTML file in the other frame and loads the bytes for the SWF associated with the HTML file. I'm using Localconnection to pass the ByteArray data in 40k chunks. Passing the entire ByteArray for a SWF through the ExternalInterface didn't work and the LocalConnection method was suggested in another [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768581/bytearray-type-coercion-failure-when-reading-from-javascript-externalinterface-c).

It works great... the first time for each HTML page. If an HTML page is revisited, I get the following error:

*Error #2044: Unhandled AsyncErrorEvent:. text=Error #2095: flash.net.LocalConnection was unable to invoke callback getBytes.*

The connection client is set and getBytes() is referenced properly. I've tried to use a unique connection string each time, the same connection string each time and a unique connection string associated with each HTML/SWF file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing the connection after you're done with it?  Only one connection can be established via LocalConnection with a given name at a given time, any others will fail.

If you close your connection when you're done in one HTML file, you may be able to reestablish connection with a later one.

Comment: Yep, attempted to close it. Tried establishing a new connection using the same string id, a GUID string id, all to no avail.